# Django ORM intersection between two date

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I have model, like this:

```
class Model(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

And in DB it's look like:

```
name    start_date    end_date       user
 1      2016-01-20    2016-01-26       1
 1      2016-01-24    2016-02-02       2
 1      2016-01-28    2016-02-10       3
 2      2016-01-19    2016-01-27       4
```

And I would find users, which will living at the same place at the same time. For example, for table behind, user '2' will living at place with name '1' and he can meet user '1' and user '3'. User '1' can meet only user '2'. '3' - only user '2'.

Could You tell me, How I can make query for this case in Django ORM?

**UPD**

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Comment: It would be better if you send the `class User(models.Model)`, the thing you need isn't obvious (at least for me)

Comment: User model just has field like first_name, last_name, it's not important.

Comment: Where is the `place` you mentioned in your question? is it the `name` column in your db? if it is, the user 2 have common place ( place with name 1 ) with user 1 and user 3, also we have the same for user 1 ( user 1 place name is "1" ) so user 1 also have common place as user 2 and user 3, but you mentioned user 1 can only meet user 2!

Comment: Yes,place is 'name' column. User 3 has different date range from user 1, that's why they cann't meet each other

Comment: I would have method like User.get_neighbours() and this have to return rows from table`Model`

Answer (score 1):

One way to check if two persons are in the same place, in the same time, is to use a date and verify which users with the same location are on that date there:

```
import datetime

date_wanted = datetime.datetime.today()
neighbour_users = User.objects.values('model_set__name').annotate(Q(start_date__lte = date_wanted) & Q(end_date__gte = date_wanted))
```

I think it's also possible to use `filter` instead of `annotate`:

```
neighbour_users = User.objects.values('model_set__name').filter(start_date__lte = date_wanted, end_date__gte = date_wanted)
```

So, using `values` we group the users in the same place and then we filter on a date to get the wanted result.

Comment: This does not answer the question. This gives the users that where at SOME place on a given date.

Comment: @nima I think your're mistaken: it gives the users in the SAME place on a given date. See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/#values) for `values()`: `values('model_set__name')` groups only the `Model` rows which have the same value in the `name` field.

Comment: It's interesting, but I will have a few rows in table for user and I want get all intersections places and dates with other users

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if this can be done in a single query, but here is how I would do it in code. Even if it could be done with a query it would be an unreadable one. You can use the same logic to get neighbors of a single user.

```
neighbors = []
models = Model.objects.all()
for m1 in models:
    for m2 in models:
        if m1.user_id != m2.user_id and \
            m1.name == m2.name and # if name represents the place
            ((m1.start_date >= m2.start_date and m1.start_date <= m2.end_date) or \
            (m2.start_date >= m1.start_date and m2.start_date <= m1.end_date)):
            neighbors.append((m1.name, m1.user, m2.user))
```

Comment: Maybe, Your code works, but i think it is slowly decision. I would like do it in DB.

Comment: This may be easier to solve if you create a new table with every date, rather than first and last.  This table could be checked for self join on name and date match.

Comment: @joelgoldstick Yes that will simplify the query in this case but I think it will complicate things in other scenarios. Also, creating this table and keeping the old one can lead to inconsistencies.